Smart tags for WPF user controls
I am trying to add smart tag to my user control. I didn't find anything for WPF so I concluded that the way of adding smart tags for windows forms applications should also work in WPF, but It doesn't. I used this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms171829(v=vs.120)
Here is the ActionList:
public class RadiobuttonGroupActionList : DesignerActionList
{
    private RadioButtonGroup radiobuttonGroup;
    private DesignerActionUIService designerActionSvc = null;

    public RadiobuttonGroupActionList(IComponent comp) : base(comp)
    {
        radiobuttonGroup = (RadioButtonGroup)comp;
        designerActionSvc = (DesignerActionUIService)GetService(typeof(DesignerActionUIService));
    }

    private PropertyDescriptor GetPropertyByName(string propName)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = default(PropertyDescriptor);
        prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(radiobuttonGroup)[propName];
        if (prop == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Property", propName);
        }
        else
        {
            return prop;
        }
    }

    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems()
    {
        DesignerActionItemCollection items = new DesignerActionItemCollection()
        {
            new DesignerActionHeaderItem("Test display name"),
            new DesignerActionPropertyItem(nameof(Title), "Test prop display name", "Appearance"),
        };
        return items;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get 
        {
            return radiobuttonGroup.Title; 
        }
        set 
        {
            GetPropertyByName(nameof(Title)).SetValue(radiobuttonGroup, value);
        }
    }
}

Here is the Designer:
public class RadiobuttonGroupDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists = null;

    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists
    {
        get
        {
            if (actionLists == null)
            {
                actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
                actionLists.Add(new RadiobuttonGroupActionList(this.Component));
            }
            return actionLists;
        }
    }
}

My question is: "How do you implement smart tag for user control in WPF?"
